# Difference between reflection and rotation of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

What is the difference between the reflection of a complex number , say $3-4i$ about the x axis and the rotation of the complex number by $90°$ in the anti clockwise direction about origin ?

Comment: What are you asking? They are different numbers because they result from different operations. The first is finding the complex conjugate, The second is multiplying by $i$. Try drawing pictures.

Answer (score 0):

The reflection about $x$ axis gives you the conjugate of the given complex number. But rotating by $90$ degrees in the counterclockwise direction is multiplying by iota. These two things are similar for a complex number lying on $x+y=0$ line, but not in general.